# ReactDOM gives Error: "Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm having difficulty rendering elements in react by using ReactDOM it results in error "Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element."

Here is my code

```
onInputChange = (event) => {

    this.setState({country: event.target.value})
    console.log(event.target.value)

    if(countryArray[0].name === event.target.value){
        console.log(countryArray[0].name)
        let h4 = <h4>Police: {countryArray[0].police}</h4>;
        let info = document.getElementsByClassName("info")
        ReactDOM.render(h4, info)

    }         
}

render (){
return (
<div class="info"></div>
  )
}
```

html code index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

what i wanted to do is, if the if statement is true then create a new html tag h4 and render it but its giving me error.

Is it because ReactDOM cant find where to render the h4? i tried to add  in the index.html i still get error

what would be the alternative here?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` gives a collection instead of a single node. Try `document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0]`

Comment: But IMO, the best way would be to keep a local state, and conditionally render the `h4` using that state value.

Comment: There are several issues with your code. I'd recommend reading React docs first before continuing working on this.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand, that works! Easwar

Comment: Yes I'm aware my code is not perfect I'm new to react and programming I'm willing to learn,  i would appreciate if you could point out the flaws?

Comment: Each time ReactDOM.render is called a new component tree is created by react independant of other trees. This might mess up interactions and re-renders between that component and its parent (which are now different react trees ) and you might lose the benifits that virtual dom provides.